# Convert array to list of params for Eloquent

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use the Eloqunt `avg` function. When I pass in my columns as a list of params, it works;

```
$this->avg('column_two','column_one');
```

But when I pass in an `$array` it doesn't;

```
$this->avg($array);
```

Here is a `dd` (like a `var_dump` of that array so you know what I'm talking about;

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => "column_0"
  1 => "column_1"
  2 => "column_2"
  3 => "column_3"
  4 => "column_4"
  5 => "column_5"
]
```

I get a really bizarre error;

```
ErrorException in Grammar.php line 58:
strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

This might seem like a basic array problem, but how can I convert that array to a list of params?

The best I can do is `implode`;

```
$array = implode(',', $array);
```

But that will just return an SQL error;

```
ERROR: column "example_0,example_1" does not exist
```

Comment: why not use `$this->avg($array[2],$array[1]);`

Comment: it's dynamic. I won't know how many items are in the array or what the column names are

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
function quote($el){
  return '"'.$el.'"';
}

$quotedArr[] = array_map('quote', $array);
$paramStr = implode(',', $quotedArr);

$this->avg($paramStr);
```

Comment: I find it hard to believe that there is no PHP function that can convert this easily for me without having to resort to loops

Comment: check the updated one, Note that this will pass all the values in the array as params

Comment: Well I'm using OOP so I don't think this can be put and called anywhere without a lot of re-writing. Give up. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the PHP [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) function.

You would use it like this:

```
$result = call_user_func_array([$this, 'avg'], $array);
```

The first parameter is a [`callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). The second parameter is the array of parameters to send to the `callable`.

---

Having said that, I'm not sure if your code is working the way you expect. Taking a look at the [code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.2.15/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1772-L1775), it seems like the `avg()` method only accepts one column in the first place. Are you sure you're getting what you want?

Comment: Ah. yeah in that case, probably not using it correctly. Damn. That was a wasted few hours.